# US Bequest Taxation

Tags: econometrics, data-request, reference-request

Is there some summary article on using variation in US bequest taxation as natural experiments? Has there been variation over time or over different states? Is there perhaps a paper that already has used this?

Answer (score 1):

Australia

> In 1979, Australia abolished federal inheritance taxes. Using daily
>   deaths data, we show that approximately 50 deaths were shifted from
>   the week before the abolition to the week after. This amounts to over
>   half of those who would have been eligible to pay the tax. Although we
>   cannot rule out the possibility that our results are driven by
>   misreporting, our results imply that over the very short run, the
>   death rate may be highly elastic with respect to the inheritance tax
>   rate.

[Did the Death of Australian Inheritance Taxes Affect Deaths?](http://andrewleigh.org/pdf/DeathAndTaxes_BEP.pdf)

Sweden

> Does taxation affect the timing of death? This is an interesting
>   example of how behavior might be affected by economic incentives. We
>   study how two changes in Swedish inheritance taxation 2004–2005 have
>   affected daily all-cause mortality. Our main result is that mortality
>   decreased by 17% the day before the expected tax repeals began.

[Living to save taxes](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176508000566)

USA

> This paper examines data from U.S. federal tax returns to shed light
>   on whether the timing of death is responsive to its tax consequences.
>   We investigate the temporal pattern of deaths around the time of
>   changes in the estate-tax system periods when living longer, or dying
>   sooner, could significantly affect estate-tax liability. We find some
>   evidence that there is a small death elasticity, although we cannot
>   rule out that what we have uncovered is ex post doctoring of the
>   reported date of death.

[Dying to Save Taxes: Evidence from Estate-Tax Returns on the Death Elasticity](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/003465303765299783)